# Shim with webpack.ProvidePlugin using a module's exported property

Tags: webpack, shim

How do I shim for example `Promise` with `webpack.ProvidePlugin` to `require('q').Promise`?

Shimming `$` in `webpack.config.js`:

```
plugins: [ new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ '$': 'jquery' }) ]
```

What is the equivalent for shimmig `Promise` using `q.Promise`?

```
// attempt:
plugins: [ new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ Promise: 'q.Promise' }) ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Promise: ['q', 'Promise']
  })
]
```

See [Webpack ProvidePlugin doc](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#provideplugin)